# BigQuery: Google Ads report transformation: Geo Performance Report: GeoStats tables are empty

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

Transfer google ads data into bigquery
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transformation

But tables

```
GeoConversionStats_[CUSTOMER_ID]
GeoStats_[CUSTOMER_ID]
```

are empty.
Why ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not encountering errors during the [Google Ads transfer setup](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-troubleshooting#google_ads_transfer_issues) it might depend on the configuration you have on Google Adwords. Check the reporting section of the [campaign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57051375/why-is-the-geostats-table-empty-when-i-use-google-ads-transfer-bigquery-data-tr) you are running documentation to see if the reports you want are included.

Here is a similar [question](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/campaigns-overview#campaign_types) where you can find more troubleshooting.