# Why is the Geostats Table empty when I use Google Ads Transfer (BigQuery Data Transfer Service)?

Tags: google-bigquery, data-transfer, google-ads-api

I am trying to get the below criterias for advertisement spending data to compute ROAS.

```
            'AccountDescriptiveName',
            'Date',
            'CampaignName',
            'CampaignId',
            'AdNetworkType2',
            'AccountTimeZone',
            'Impressions',
            'Clicks',
            'Cost',
            'AccountCurrencyCode',
            'Conversions',
            'CountryCriteriaId'
```

The CountryCriteriaId is only available in GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT which is represented by GeoStats table in Google Ads Transfer Service.

I have found some tables like CampaignStats Table are not empty. However, the GeoStats Report is empty with 0 rows.

How can I get results for GeoStats table with Google Ads Transfer Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyon ewho has tried to help me with my issue.

I have found that the reason was that currently, I was only running UAC and there are only few reports which can be downloaded for UAC. (Check [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/mobile-app-campaigns#reporting) for the available report types)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AdWords documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/geo-performance-report), by default the report only includes rows where:

```
IsTargetingLocation = true
```

Maybe that is the reason why you are getting empty tables with the Transfer Service, you could try changing the predicate to:

```
IsTargetingLocation = false
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou very much for your advice. Do you know how I can make that setting when I am using BigQuery Data Transfer Service? (I am currently not using Google Ads API)

Comment: It seems that the BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google Ads doesn't let you change the predicate(filter) for the report. Maybe you could try using the API to make sure there is data in that report. If it is, maybe you should consider using a third-party tool to do a more customized transfer.

Also, I found that the CountryCriteriaId is also available on the [Shopping Performance Report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/shopping-performance-report), you could try to get it from that table.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but I also have issues with the GEO and Google Storage Transfer service and seems there is no answer.
It's not empty but the numbers don't match.  E.g. a query like this

SELECT
_DATA_DATE, sum(clicks)
FROM `_project_._dataset_.GeoStats_XXX`
where LocationType='LOCATION_OF_PRESENCE'
and IsTargetingLocation IN (true, false)
group by 1

returns a smaller number than the real one.